# How to get all the 0's from scanf input in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am new to C and need some help here.
I want to save all the zeros into a variable.

E.g:

```
    int number1 = 0;
     int number2 = 0;
     int number3 = 0;

     printf("Please enter the number in the following format( int,int,int)");
     scanf("%d,%d,%d", &number1, &number2,  &number3);

 // Let's say user enters 1,000,000 (a million)
 // I want to be able to print each of the numbers such as
 // number1 = 1 
 // number2 = 000
 // number3 = 000
```

At the moment when i do a printf statement for 1,000,000 i only get 1,0,0

My end goal here is to convert that decimal number to a binary number

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preserve leading zeroes, you should read the values as strings, rather than integers.

Answer (score 2):

The posted code is reading three integers,  separated by commas.

naturally, the results are 1 and 0 and 0

regarding this statement:

```
// Let's say user enters 1,000,000 (a million)
```

we can read it as a million, but the posted code (which reads three integers, separated by commas)  will only see 1 and 0 and 0

To keep all the zeros, read the whole input as a char array.  Then parse the actual number from the resulting char array by first squeezing out the commas, then converting to a single integer.

EDIT:

suggested algorithms to parse the actual value

```
char buffer[100];
int inputNum;
if( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) ) 
{
    for( char *source = buffer, char *destination = buffer;
        *source;
        source++ )
    {
        if( isdigit( *source ) )
        {
            *destination = *source;
            destination++;
        }
    }
    *destination = '\0';
    inputNum = atoi( buffer );
}
```

there are simpler ways, like:

```
char buffer[100]; 
int inputNum = 0;

if( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) ) 
{ 
    for( int i=0; buffer[i]; i++) 
    { 
        if( isdigit(buffer[i]) 
        { 
            inputNum *= 10; 
            inputNum += (buffer[i] - '0');
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: i've known C for almost a week now , could someone help me with an example code for parsing and converting to integer?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
char number1[80];
char number2[80];
char number3[80];

printf("Please enter the number in the following format(int,int,int)\n");
scanf(" %[0-9] , %[0-9] , %[0-9]", number1, number2, number3);

printf("%s, %s, %s", number1, number2, number3);
```

To convert a string to an `int`, you can write `atoi(numberx)`